# Построение графика функции

Tags: delphi

Как построить график функции в делфи

```
x=(1+cos(t))*a*cos(t), y=(1+cos(t))*a*sin(t), a>0, 0<=t<360
```

?

Comment: Что вам не ясно? Что именно не получается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Задаете `a`
2. В цикле от 0 до 360 считаете `x` и `y`
3. Например, на `TImage` переносите изображение (рисуете по точкам из п.2), главное правильно рассчитать и отмасштабировать график. Учитывая, что координаты на `TImage` начинаются с верхнего левого угла.

При необходимости меняете `a` и снова повторяете процедуру. Все просто.

Answer (score 1):

Ни в коем случае не пользуйтесь TImage для построения графиков. В Дельфи имеется компонент TChart, специально предназначенный для этой цели.

Comment: Какая же "катастрофа" может от этого случиться?

Comment: Конечно, никакой "катастрофы" не случится, уважаемый @insolor. Просто, следует применять возможности ИСР и забивать гвозди не ломом или бревном, а молотком, специально предназначенным для этой операции. Тем более, что рисовать можно и прямо на форме, не применяя даже TImage, у которого никакого преимущества в этом смысле перед формой нет; а у TChart - громадные преимущества.

Comment: То, что компонент имеется совершенно не значит, что его необходимо применять для учебных целей. У TImage перед формой есть просто офигенное преимущество, если нужно разместить на ней еще несколько контролов. Не говоря уже о том, что раздувать холивар из-за компонента, приведенного в качестве примера - это по-нашему! Слова для поиска в моем ответе: задать начальные значения, цикл, по точкам. И все же не понятно, чем вам так не угодил TImage, может я чего-то не знаю?

Comment: @BuilderC, а если цель ТС именно научиться самому работать с рисованием в Delphi?

Comment: @Dex. Никакой священной войны никто с Вами не ведет. К "словам для поиска" также нет никаких претензий. Все, что я хотел сказать, я сказал и считаю тему закрытой.